# How can I map strings with periods to symbols in a Rails 5 database migration?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration, symbols

I have a PSQL database I need to pull data from for a Rails 5.4 application. I have zero control over this database, including the naming conventions.

In this PSQL database, let's say there is a table called `warehouse_items` with an attribute named `ITEM_WH.SERIAL` that contains a warehouse item's serial number.

Then, let's say I try to create a migration for this table that incorporates this attribute as the primary key:

```
  def change
    create_table :warehouse_items do |t|
      t.string :ITEM_WH.SERIAL, null: false
    end
  end
```

The scene ends badly, as you might imagine, in a cavalcade of anger and fear. The `.SERIAL` is interpreted as a method on the symbol `:ITEM_WH`, rather than as a cohesive whole `:ITEM_WH.SERIAL`.

I know I can use strings instead of symbols here (i.e. `'ITEM_WH.SERIAL'`), but I've heard that's less efficient.

Is there some way to map the string in the SQL database to a symbol in the migration, basically telling my application that, "Yes, I know the database attribute is `ITEM_WH.SERIAL` and I want you to pull that information, but please map it to the symbol `:item_wh_serial` in your own schema"?

Is it even that bad to use strings instead of symbols in a database migration?

What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this PSQL database, [there is a column] named ITEM_WH.SERIAL ..
>
> ```
>   t.string :ITEM_WH.SERIAL, null: false
> ```
>
> The scene ends badly .. [it is a ruby syntax error]

Option 1: fix the symbol literal

```rb
t.string :"ITEM_WH.SERIAL", null: false
```

Option 2: use a string instead of a symbol

```rb
t.string "ITEM_WH.SERIAL", null: false
```

Comment: Option 1 seems like exactly what I need, thanks!

I'll give it a go, and then report back.